# Replace quotes which are not inside word

Tags: java, regex

I have a long string containing several words.

Some of these words have apostrophe for eg . don't . some words have apostrophe outside the words for example '''movieis great ''' or ''lot of apostrophe ''''' .

I want to remove all the apostrophe that is not a part of the word.

> > For example in the string = don't try to ''''remove apostr inside'''' word'.
> >     the output should be don't try to remove apostr inside word.

```
I wrote the regex for it .*[^a-z]'[^a-z].* But I am not getting the desired output in my java code.

String s = "don't try to ''''remove apostr inside'''' word'";
s = s.replace(".*[^a-z]'[^a-z].*", " ");
```

Comment: Use `.replaceAll("(?U)\\B'\\b|\\b'\\B|\\B'\\B", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `.replace()` only replaces literal strings and does not allow regex as the search argument.

You may use a regex that will match apostrophes not enclosed with word boundaries:

```
String s = "don't try to ''''remove apostr inside'''' word' 'żoł'";
s = s.replaceAll("(?U)\\B'\\b|\\b'\\B|\\B'\\B", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

See the [online Java demo](http://ideone.com/OlTSkq)

Here, `\b` is a word boundary, `\B` a position other than word boundary and `(?U)` makes the `\b` and `\B` Unicode aware.

Comment: It works for most of the cases, but for a case like belo''''o the outut should br belo o and not beloo

Comment: Then you need to use `.replaceAll("(?U)\\b'{2,}\\b", " ")` before.

Comment: but this would fail for the above cases like String s = "'Abc"